# Failed to connect to the BizTalkMgmtDb database from BizTalk Management REST Api's

Tags: rest, biztalk, biztalk-2016

I am using the [BizTalk Feature Pack 2](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/biztalk-docs/blob/master/biztalk/core/install-and-configure-the-management-rest-apis-in-biztalk-server.md) and enabled the BizTalk Server Management REST API's.

When I tried to use the API to resume a suspended messages getting the below error.

> Failed to connect to the BizTalkMgmtDb database on 'serverName'

Unable find any logs. All the services are running with same domain account that is used for app pool identity.

Answer (score 0):

The REST API's were deployed to IIS with custom window domain account.
After disabling the Impersonation in IIS, I am able to call the API's without this error.